# An example that the circle group $\mathrm{S}^1$ embeds in $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: group-theory

I read [this tweet](https://twitter.com/CihanPostsThms/status/1657517477926977543).

> The circle group $\mathrm{S}^1$ embeds in $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb{N})$

Someone give [an example](https://twitter.com/nicolas_gues/status/1657695583656722434)

> An explicit one is given by the subgroup of permutations that are
> (infinite) composition of the form (2n 2n+1)

Why is this an embedding?

Comment: I don't think the tweet is arguing that that is an embedding of $S^1$.

Comment: What exactly is an "infinite composition"? Regardless, this example produces only elements of order $2$, no? So it can't possibly be related to the embedding.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 6):

Here’s a construction of the embedding that you want:

Consider the short exact sequence (of Abelian groups) $$0\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\overset{\text{inc.}}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow X\to 0$$ where “$\text{inc.}$” is the natural inclusion map. It’s not hard to see that $X$ has continuum cardinality and moreover that the nonzero integers act (by scaling) invertibly on $X$, so that $X$ is naturally a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and in particular $X\simeq\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{Q}$ (not canonically). As $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is injective, the aforementioned short exact sequence splits (non-canonically), yielding a (non-canonical) isomorphism $$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\ \simeq\ \left(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\right)\times \prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{Q}.$$ So it suffices to find an embedding of the latter into $$\text{Sym}\left(\mathbb{N}\right)\ \simeq\ \text{Sym}\left(\left(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\right)\sqcup \coprod_{n= 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{Q}\right)$$ (the (non-canonical) isomorphism between the two by cardinality), of which there’s a fairly obvious choice.

Comment: $\prod$ is the categorical product of Abelian groups, not the “direct product” (which is really the *co*product). $\coprod$ is the coproduct (“disjoint union”) of sets. The cardinalities all work out.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.